# Rope lying on table and hanging through hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, string

In Kleppner's Mechanics, there is a problem given as

> A rope of mass $M$ and length $l$ lies on a frictionless table, with
> a short portion, $l_0$, hanging through a hole. Initially the rope is at rest.
> Find the general equation for the length of rope hanging through hole.

In the solution, the problem is solved by using momentum equation given as-
Suppose at time $t$, $x$ length of ripe is hanging
Initial momentum at time t, $P_t$= $Mv$
Momentum at time $t+dt$, $P(t+dt) = M(v+dv)$
Rate of change of momentum = $Mdv/dt$
dp/dt = Force on rope
$Mdv/dt = Mxg/l$
Then we can solve for the expression for $x$.

The question is that while rope is hanging from table then hanging part moves with velocity $v$ in downward direction and the part which rest on table moves with velocity $v$ in horizontal direction and the force of weight of hanging part acts in downward direction.
Then how we write the momentum of rope as $Mv$ and $M(v+dv)$, shouldn't velocity involve separate x and y component in velocity?

Like how we write the initial and final momentum of rope in vector notation?

How we write the momentum of whole rope using a single velocity in one y-component(not including x component) and equate the change of momentum to downward force of weight?

Please explain.

Comment: I do not know why you used momentum, just use forces (split the rope into horizontal and vertical parts and add a tension between these parts. You will get the same equation though

Comment: the reason you can use a single momentum is because the problem is equivalent to one in which the rope is straight but the force acts only on the part of the rope that does not touch the table

Comment: @Wolphram Jonny, in your second comment, may you give somewhat detailed explanation to support your reasoning like how a single momentum is used?

Comment: Just imagine a horizontal rope, that instead of bending down on the table is kept straight and the force on that section is proportional to the length of that section. The fact that the rope is bent does not matter in this particular case, as both sections of the rope will be pushed with the same force in both examples, so the acceleration will be the same

Comment: Yeah, acceleration will definitely be same in both the cases. But is there any way we can rigorously justify that (Mv) yhat =  (mv) xhat + ((M-m)v) yhat where m is the mass lying on the table?

Comment: Please explain I am not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demonstrate how considering horizontal and vertical components of momentum gives the same result.

Let the mass of the horizontal part be $m_1$, mass of the hanging part be $m_2$, tension in the string be T, and the linear mass density be $\lambda$

$F_x = m_1 \frac {dv}{dt} + v \frac {dm_1}{dt} = T$

$\therefore m_1a-v^2\lambda=T$    $\therefore v^2\lambda=m_1 a-T$

$F_y = m_2 \frac {dv}{dt} + v \frac {dm_2}{dt} = m_2g-T$

$\therefore m_2a+v^2\lambda=m_2g-T$

$\therefore m_2a+m_1a-T=m_2g-T$

$\therefore Ma=m_2g$

You can further use $ m_2x=Ml$ to get the same result as the one in your book. However, the method used in the book is much shorter and easier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there would be tension acting on m1 which cause it to move. And also the net force on m2 would be m2g-T. And tension in both equation when added get cancelled.

Comment: I have also a doubt that if we add the x and y direction momentum then how the momentum get added simply like scalar it should be vector addition then T should not be cancelled?

Comment: we have not added the x and y direction momentum, i simply found out the value of $v^2 \lambda$ and substituted it.

Comment: Ok, sorry I think the other way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Falling chains and ropes  are  notoriously difficult problems with a long and disputed literature going back to Tait and Cayley in the 19th centure. I recommend starting with the article listed below. If you get a different answer from your textbook, you may be write and the book wrong.

Article:

A uniform explanation of all falling chain phenomena

Mark Denny

American Journal of Physics 88, 94 (2020); https://doi.org/10.1119/10.0000304

It might be behind a paywall I'm afraid.